# Remove last directory from URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My question is, How can remove last directory using htaccess rule.

```
http://mywedding.com/anandn/
should load content of
http://mywedding.com/anandn/theme/

OR

http://mywedding.com/mamtaandkuldip/
should load content of
http://mywedding.com/mamtaandkuldip/theme/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just replace `/(.*/)$` with `/` ? The dollar makes it the last part of the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/theme/ [L]
```

Comment: When I enter http://mywedding.com/anandn/ it should show the content of http://mywedding.com/anandn/theme/

Comment: Hmm your question says opposite of it. Let me change it

Comment: ok good but we have so many option like anandn, mamtaandkuldip. So can't make it as a rule instead of static values ??

Comment: so `http://mywedding.com/foo/` OR `http://mywedding.com/bar/` would also load `http://mywedding.com/theme/foo/` OR `http://mywedding.com/theme/bar/`?

Comment: Yes it should. Did you try?

Comment: Yes but not working. http://192.168.10.148/Test1 should load content of http://192.168.10.148/Test1/Tess2. So I put code here is Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/Test2/ [L] in Test1 folder. http://192.168.10.148/ This URL is my local

Comment: Question is about adding `/theme/` in the URL internally so how can it add `/Test2/` all of a sudden?

Comment: It is NOT `/themes/` it is **`/theme/`** read your own question

Comment: Hi I need some change in this rule. So pl help me out.

Comment: This rule is applied to all directories in root, but I need to exclude(not to apply) some directories. So Pl help for that.

Comment: You can add a condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dir1|dir2)` in this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Inside 
mywedding.com/anandn/index.php 
write the following code
header("location:mywedding.com/anandn/theme/");

it will redirect you to your site.