# .HTACCESS remove directory and subdirectories from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an URL, for example:

```
localhost/templates
```

and I have an URL, for example:

```
localhost/system/classes/site
```

How is it possible to remove all directories with htaccess?
As result, I want my link as next example:

```
localhost/file.php
```

currently I have this code in my htaccess, but it works only for /templates

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)templates 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ templates/$1 [L] 


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: [remove-last-directory-from-url-using-htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636178/remove-last-directory-from-url-using-htaccess?rq=1)

Comment: Doens't work.. I don't wont only the last, i want all directories and subdirectories to remove